# HTML form file not uploading

Tags: php, file-upload, forms, php-ini

I have an HTML form as the following:

```
<form id="addTrack" action="/worship/script/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded" id="addTrackFile"/>
    <label>Key Title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="addTrackTitle"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="addTrackId"/><br>
</form>
<button onclick="uploadAddTrack()">Upload</button>
<button onclick="closeAddTrack()">Close</button>
```

When I submit the form the file uploads to the server properly, but when it gets redirected to the PHP action script, it gets stopped at the first error catch. The script then dumps the `$_FILES` variable which it returns as an empty array. As you can see in the code below, I also have it echo the error, but it also echoes an empty string.

Why am I not getting a file in the `$_FILES` array?

### My PHP Code:

```
$id=$_POST["id"];
$name=$_POST["title"];

$name = str_replace(" ","",$name);

$allowed_filetypes = array('.mp3','.m4a','.wav','.wma');

$filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

$target = "../audio/"; 
$target = $target . $id. "_".$name.$ext; 
$ok=1; 

if ($_FILES['uploaded']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    //------------This is where it gets stopped-----------------//

        var_dump($_FILES);
    echo $_FILES["uploaded"]["error"];
    return;
}

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die("This file type is not allowed");

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
include("updateDB.php");

header("Location:/worship/cpanel/?autoload=$id");
}
```

The size of the file I am uploading is 9mb.

### My php.ini relevant info

> file_uploads: On
>
> upload_max_filesize: 25M
>
> upload_tmp_dir: no value
>
> max_post_size: 8M

Comment: Is the directory you're uploading to writeable?

Comment: I don't know. How do I check?

Comment: Are you sending form via ajax or what triggers submit?

Comment: Depends on the OS that the server is running. If linux, you would navigate to the parent directory, and run `ls -l` . If it's a windows server, you right click on the directory and view the permissions of the IIS_USR account

Comment: @mituw16 The permissions for the directory are 0755.

Comment: @AngularAddict I am just submitting the form with `$("form#addTrack").submit();`

Comment: That is the problem then. In linux, `755` means readable, executeable by all, but only writeable by file owner

Comment: @mituw16 that can be ok though if the web/group user owns that directory. It depends on the setup.

Comment: True True, is the web/group user the owner of the directory?

Comment: @mituw16 How do I check that?

Comment: When you ran `ls -l`  who did it list before 755?

Comment: Hold on. I found the file permissions through FTP. Let me login to SSH.

Comment: If it is owned by anyone other than the webserver, you need to either change the directory permissions to `777` or using the `chown` command have the webserver take ownership of the directory

Comment: @David check you PHP.ini file. make sure the POST size is larger the 8M. because that is the default and you're sending info that is 9MB. `; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M`

Comment: It says the owner and group are both the user.

Comment: @Pjack That was the problem. The max post was 8M. Duh lol. Thank you so much for your help! :) If you want to post it as an answer, I'll gladly upvote/accept!

Comment: @David ok no problem. Answered to keep it out of the unanswered queue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check you PHP.ini file. make sure the POST size is larger the 8M. because that is the default and you're sending info that is 9MB.

```
 `; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.

post_max_size = 8M`
```